# the best way for learning is drumming in

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "Drumming in" mean "repetition" when we say "the best way for learning is drumming in" ?

Comment: [dictionary.reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/drum) **drum** - to drive or force by persistent repetition: *to drum an idea into someone.*

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is "[drumming something into one's head](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drum+into)," under the dubious theory that a person's head and a drum head are similar enough that long-term, forceful, repetitive pounding aids learning.